# spark: minimize the number of calls to filter function

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the following code: (python)

```
def do_mongo_filter(record):
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
    collection = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)[<db_name>][<collection_name>]
    return collection.find_one({'_id': record[0]}) is not None

rdd_after_filter = rdd_before_filter.filter(do_mongo_filter)
```

My questions are:
 1. I know that the mongo guys have written this spark connector "pymongo_spark", but as far as i understand i can only use it to write a full rdd, or read a full collection.
I cant use it to filter results, like what i need in this example. as i correct?
 2. Its going to be terrible using it like this, import over and over again and establish a connection, any suggestions?
 3. Its basically continuing the second question, lets say the rdd is of 10M values, and its a key value rdd, and the keys are sorted. What can i do not to call the filter function 10M times, but only on the unique keys?

I tried to think in the lines of:

```
only_unique_keys = rdd_before_filter.keys().map(lambda x: (x,x)).reduceByKey(x,y: x)
keys_in_mongo = only_unique_keys.filter(do_mongo_filter)
rdd_after_filter = rdd_before_filter.filter(lambda x: x in keys_in_mongo.toLocalIterator())
```

But again, its a lot of records.

Comment: Assuming 10M records in the RDD - how does it compare to collection size?

Comment: about the same, my main issue is to not bombard the mongo

Comment: The Mongo Spark Connector will send filters from the SQLContext to Mongo and it will only pass the filtered information back to Spark.  You can also write custom aggregation pipelines to further manipulate the data. The catch is it works on DataFrames rather than raw RDD's which may be an issue if your documents are contain wildly different data.

Comment: can you offer a code example?

Comment: Just to clarify do you want to filter your existing RDD based on the fact that data exists in MongoDB? Or would you rather create an RDD from MongoDB?  If its the first scenario it will be expensive as you need to check in 10M items in an RDD also exist in MongoDB. The only way to do that is to query MongoDB - you could use $in queries to reduce the number of queries and broadcast variables so you share the MongoClient.  However a join of two RDD's one containing the whole collection maybe a more efficient way to check. It depends on how much overlap is expected between the two datasources.

Comment: First scenario.

small fix to the size assumption, the rdd will be about 3M records, the Mongo Collection is currently 10M but can get to 50M in the near future.

So getting all the info to spark memory is not something that can scale...

Do you have anything better then, what i suggested here
using 
do_mongo_filter(record), that imports pymongo inside?